# Sorted ArrayList not displaying?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting

```
ArrayList <String> cdcollection = new ArrayList();

private void initButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Collections.addAll(cdcollection, "renier\n",  "mert\n", "rain\n", "mylen", "dreb\n"    );
    initButton.setEnabled(false);
}

private void displayButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String title1 = "Original Order\n\n";
    String title2 = "Sorted Order\n\n";

    String collection = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cdcollection.size(); i++)  {
        collection = collection + cdcollection.get(i);
    }
    mainTextArea.setText(title1 + collection);

    Collections.sort(cdcollection);

    for (int j = 0; j < cdcollection.size(); j++)  {
        mainTextArea.setText(title2 + collection.get(j));
    }
}

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    cdcollection.add(cdtitleInput.getText());
}

private void removeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    cdcollection.remove(cdcollection.size()-1);
}
```

For this line mainTextArea.setText(title2 + collection.get(j)); I get an error "cannot find symbol" and it doesn't display when I run the program. All I see is this:

Original Order

renier
mert
rain
mylen
dreb

Comment: `collection.get(j)` - you're trying to perform `get()` on a Java `String`, which doesn't have that method. Your code compiles with this error? I think what's happening is your build is breaking and you're running an older build of your program. Maybe you meant `cdcollection.get(j)`?

Comment: Sorry, this question is quite confusing; I asked a new question that hopefully makes more sense: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692795/displaying-an-arraylist-with-and-without-sorting

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `collection` as a string like `String collection = "";`. There is no method called `get(j)` in String class. Try to use your arraylist object `cdcollection`. Also take of the creation of arraylist. You have done like `ArrayList <String> cdcollection = new ArrayList();`, try to use generics both the sides like `ArrayList <String> cdcollection = new ArrayList<String>();`, otherwise you might get unnecessary warnings.

EDIT:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<String> cdcollection = new ArrayList();
    Collections.addAll(cdcollection, "renier\n", "mert\n", "rain\n",
            "mylen", "dreb\n");

    String title1 = "Original Order\n\n";
    String title2 = "Sorted Order\n\n";

    String collection = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cdcollection.size(); i++) {
        collection = collection + cdcollection.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println(title1 + collection);

    Collections.sort(cdcollection);
    System.out.println(cdcollection);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this question is quite confusing; I asked a new question that hopefully makes more sense: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692795/displaying-an-arraylist-with-and-without-sorting

Comment: i took your code without the swing code. i just edited my answer. it prints the sorted list exactly.