# Displaying an ArrayList with and without sorting?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorted ArrayList not displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692561/sorted-arraylist-not-displaying)

Code:

```
  String title1 = "Original Order\n\n";
  String title2 = "Sorted Order\n\n";

  String collection = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < cdcollection.size(); i++)  {
  collection = collection + cdcollection.get(i);
  }
  mainTextArea.setText(title1 + collection);


  Collections.sort(cdcollection);

  String temp = "";
  for (int j = 0; j < cdcollection.size(); j++)  {
  temp += cdcollection.get(j);
  }
  mainTextArea.setText(title2 + temp);
```

Comment: That question doesn't make much sense so I asked this new question. I didn't word that question properly and so I didn't get the answers I  was looking for.

Comment: [Edition](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10692561/edit).

Comment: Please indent your code properly. And provide the complete and exact error message.

Comment: Like in the previous question, you are applying `.get(j)` to an array! that is not a valid array method. Does your code compile?

Comment: @vainolo `get` is a valid method of `List`

Comment: @GuillaumePolet if you carefully see he is not calling that with a List object but with a String object.

Comment: @May: If your question wasn't clear, you should improve it, instead of opening a new, nearly identical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code without the swing code and the list is sorted properly. See the code below

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<String> cdcollection = new ArrayList();
    Collections.addAll(cdcollection, "renier\n", "mert\n", "rain\n",
            "mylen", "dreb\n");

    String title1 = "Original Order\n\n";
    String title2 = "Sorted Order\n\n";

    String collection = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cdcollection.size(); i++) {
        collection = collection + cdcollection.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println(title1 + collection);

    Collections.sort(cdcollection);
    System.out.println(cdcollection);
}
```

The for loop you used here

```
 for (int j = 0; j < cdcollection.size(); j++)  {
      mainTextArea.setText(title2 + collection.get(j));
 }
```

Dont add the `title2` in the loop and calling setText in loop will over write the old text. Append all the string from the list in a temp string and in the last set in the in the `mainTextArea`. Something like

```
 String temp = "";
 for (int j = 0; j < cdcollection.size(); j++)  {
      temp += cdcollection.get(j));
 }
 mainTextArea.setText(title2 + temp);
```

But this is definitely a duplicate as mentioned by Alexander. you could have edited the same question.

Comment: For this line temp += collection.get(j)); I get the following error "Cannot find symbol
 symbol:   method get(int)
 location: class java.lang.String"

Comment: i took your code and pasted. I will edit that..it should be cdcollection.get(j).

Comment: Thanks but now it displays only the sorted order...

Comment: it would be good if you can update the latest code in your question. i will be very happy to help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11537/discussion-between-may-and-raddykrish)

Comment: Heard about the simplified for-loop?

Comment: @userunknown yes i do...just wanted to give the same code back to the submitter. will take care henceforth. thanks!!!

Comment: @raddykrish: I'm asking, because one of his errors wouldn't have occurred with the simplified loop, I guess. He now has changed the question.

Comment: @userunknown yeah he changed the question and he chatted with me and i gave some suggestions and it worked. yes using the simpliified would have avoided the index based accessing of the list and that would have avoided his error exactly

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code of your `displayButtonActionPerformed` method with the following:

```
  mainTextArea.append("Original Order\n\n");

  for (String s:cdcollection)  {
        mainTextArea.append(s);
        mainTextArea.append("\n");
  }
  List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(cdcollection);
  Collections.sort(copy);

  mainTextArea.append("Sorted Order\n\n");
  for (String s:copy)  {
        mainTextArea.append(s);
        mainTextArea.append("\n");
  }
```

In your second iteration, you iterate over "collection" instead of "cdcollection".

Calling setText(), replaces the entire text of a textarea. Use `append()` instead.